# Is it on-topic to ask a question on how the Elo system can be adapted for multiplayer games and games where the margin of victory matters?

Tags: discussion

I initially asked [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/322809/194935) on Arqade.SE, but found out that it's off-topic.

Is it on-site here to ask about how the Elo system can be modified to work for multiplayer games and games where the margin of victory matters?

---

Please add any required tags, as the one I used might be insufficient.

Comment: We have [quite a few questions & answers about Elo-inspired ranking systems](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=elo). Scan through those and you might find some.suggestions relevant to your application. :)

Comment: @DMGregory Thanks a lot, quite a few of them deal with my question! I'll look into them and let you know! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see why it wouldn't be, but (without really knowing too much about the workings of Elo) I would guess you should ask two separate questions, not one trying to address both changes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The link provided by DMGregory was useful in clearing up my doubts about Elo for multiplayer games, so my question (which I'll ask soon) will focus only on the principles involved in extending the Elo system to games where the margin of victory matters. Thanks again, I've accepted your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Yes it would be on topic. Just note that scoring systems is a topic that only partially overlaps with game development - it's widely used in sports, non-video games, and studied as a topic in mathematics. So you might find better answers in another stack, like math.stackexchange.com.

This stack would be best for scoring systems as applied to video games.